# Using jQuery to perform a smooth scroll of a page using named anchors?

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm working on a one page website and would like to include named anchors across it for each section.

I also would like it so when you click a hyperlink on the navigation, it scrolls down/up the page smoothly rather than a quick jump.

What is the simplest copy and paste type jQuery script that I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a quick little script that should do the trick:

replace `a` with the selector of your links in the navigation. I've found scrolling `body, html` makes the scrolling a lot smoother

```
$('.nav_item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //used to prevent default actions
    var _this = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: _this.offset().top
    }, 400) // how ever fast you want it to scroll.

});
```

Comment: Don't forget to prevent the default action of the link click.

Comment: Doesn't the click event bubble up only after this function has completed, i.e. the normal click would jump the page to the exact same location that it has already reached?
Good practice to include the preventDefault, I'm just curious :)

Comment: @locrizak thanks. Further question though just to clarify... I made this the first line: $('news').click(function(e){

I added the named anchor as this <a name="news"></a> and then on the nav made the hyperlink this <a href="#news">News</a>

The anchor works, but didn't smooth scroll. What have I done incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: `news` is not a selector, you need `.news` is it is a class or `#news` if it is an id. @Flater updated my answer long before you made your comment, now im a little confused :p

Comment: No I actually meant that is isn't required, as the normal scroll will only occur after the smooth scroll. After the smooth scroll has occured, the page should then 'jump' to the exact same location it has just scrolled to. Shouldn't it?

Comment: No doesn't actually seem to work. Look at my source at http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/ - As you can see I've included the JS at the top and the links off the menu are <a href="#about">About</a> which point to <a id="work_1" class="section_wrapper">. It just jumps with no scrolling.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you add `class='nav_item'` to the nav items at the top this should work.

Comment: @locrizak thanks. I just used that and still no luck. Please see my code at http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/ - Did I put the class='nav_item' in the correct place, on the hyperlinks?

Comment: You didn't change everything.. Please take another look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

this is not a really exact script. If htere's a complete link in 'href' attribute (for example, htref="http://kremlin.ru/#putin" (and not just #putin) ) then the script won't work! In order the script could work with any type of links in href, you need to parse the attribute and delete everything that if BEFORE the mark '#'
Here is the completely working one:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //used to prevent default actions
    var linker = $(this).attr('href');
    var linkerN=linker;
        linkerN=linkerN.replace(/^.*\#/, '');
        // alert(linkerN);
     if(linker.indexOf('#') > 0){

        $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('a'+'[name='+linkerN+']').offset().top}, 400);
    }
    else{
    //alert ('no "#" in link, going to go to:'+linker);
    window.location.href=linker;
   }
});
```